# Multiple h:form in view not working

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a p:selectOneMenu component that updates another one this way :

```
<h:form id="formaComboInstrumento">                                
     <p:selectOneMenu value="#{CDat.instrumentoSeleccionado}">
         <f:selectItem  itemValue="" itemLabel="--Selecciona un examen--"/>
         <f:selectItems value="#{CDat.mapaInstrumentos.entrySet()}" var="var" itemValue="#{var.key}" itemLabel="#{var.value}" />     
         <p:ajax listener="#{CDat.cambioComboInstrumento}" update=":subtipo"/>                           
     </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>

<p:selectOneMenu  id="subtipo" value="#{CDat.mapaInstrumentosSubtipo}" >
   <f:selectItem  itemValue="" itemLabel="--Selecciona un examen--"/>
   <f:selectItems value="#{CDat.mapaInstrumentosSubtipo.entrySet()}" var="var" itemValue="#{var.key}" itemLabel="#{var.value}" />               
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

That works perfectly.Then a bit down I have another form with a p:commandButton for the submit/processing, this way :

```
<h:form id="formaProcesarAplicacion">
   <p:growl id="growl3" sticky="false" life="3000"/>                                            
   <p:commandButton value="Procesar aplicacion" action="#{CDat.procesarAplicacion}" update="growl3"/>
</h:form>
```

Unfortunately this last form never touches the bean(I know because when i remove the first form,the method/action procesarAplicacion makes the processing and shows values), making imposible doing the data processing.

Any idea,suggestion?

I'm using primefaces 3.5,mojarra 2.1.22,tomcat 7 and Eclipse Juno.

Comment: Probably not related with the problem, but your `<p:selectOneMenu  id="subtipo" />` should be encapsulated in a `h:form`

Comment: Can you give us a full picture of your view?

Comment: @skuntsel It's pretty basic one inputfield,three oneselectmenu and the button

Comment: Ideally your first block of code should not work. As component outside of form can not update after ajax. Please check out if there is any other form tag inside your xhtml page

Comment: @Jitesh I'm pretty sure that I have ONLY TWO forms in the view that's not the problem

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Thanks you were right after putting the p:select OneMenu inside the form now works like a charm. I cannot upvote a comment but if you post as answer I'll do.Edit. sorry in fact I don't even know if I can upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment, your problem is related to the `<p:selectOneMenu id="subtipo" />` that is not encapsulated inside the `<h:form />`.

Since you ommited that, this menu value is never posted to the bean. Probably that you got a validation or processing error that was blocking your `p:commandButton` action.